# how to set the background color of the status bar during the launching phase

Tags: android, android-styles, android-statusbar

Before my app was with android:targetSdkVersion="14" but i decide to make it a little more modern and update it to android:targetSdkVersion="22". However now i have a little problem, the color of the top status bar during the launch phase is now gray (like on the picture) and i would prefer to have it black (like it's was before).

[image]

Any idea what i need to do to have my status bar black again during the launch phase ?

**NOTE**

I would like to change the color of the statusbar via the styles.xml. actually i try to add

```
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

didn't help! this question is not a duplicate of other because i can set the StatusBar color to be black without any problem after the app is launched or fully loaded. I need to setup the black background for the statusbar during the **launching phase**, i mean when user click on the icon of the app their is something like a launch screen (with a define to be black via `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>`) but the statusbar color of this launch sreen is gray (only if android:targetSdkVersion="22")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Easiest Way is**  :got to res -> value -> styles  and add this

1: Add this in your color xml file

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

2:Add this in your styles.xml file

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**Note:**

1. colorprimary is for Actionbar
2. colorPrimaryDark is for Statusbar
3. your can change these colors and u could get ur required result .

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

hope answerd the question if its useful then vote up

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately this didn't work :(  <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item> i can't change it because it's also use for other think. i just need to change to color of the status bar

Comment: @loki i have edit my answer check it out

Comment: thanks Abubakar :) it's work now

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.background););
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  // Change color of action bar
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0099CC")));
```